# Calling Bootstrap modal window from c# method

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having a bit of a strange issue where I have a bootstrap modal window that I am trying to call from a c# method.
Here is the code of my modal window

```
    <div id="TechnicalRejectModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter reason for rejection</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTechnicalRejectModal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button id="technicalrejectmodalbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" onclick="">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling the following javascript and c# code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $('#TechnicalRejectModal').modal('show');
    }
 </script>
```

---

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { openModal(); });", true);
```

The issue I'm having is that the modal windows only seems to appear when I put it behind a button that execute the c# code and nothing else. I'm trying to get it to be called as part of a larger method that will allow the user to enter text into the textbox and then output it to a variable that I can insert into a SQL backend DB along with some other parameters. The modal window is called from a button from within a list view which is also passing parameters back to the C# code

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Tech Reject" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RequestID") %>' CommandName="TechReject"/>
```

How can I get the modal window to popup and allow the user to input details and then continue on with the code block? The issue is related to the code running after the launching the modal window appears to be make it disappear straight away. If anyone has an alternative solution to get this to work please let me know although I would prefer to stay with Bootstrap as opposed to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of playing around I managed to get it sorted. This is what I now have.

The list view button looks like this. It passes the requestID to the modal window:

```
    <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-id='<%# Eval("RequestID") %>'  title="Reject" class="open-BusinessRejectModal btn btn-primary" href="#BusinessRejectModal">Business Reject</a>
    </td>
```

Javascipt is used to push the "requestid" to the modal textbox

```
 $(document).on("click", ".open-BusinessRejectModal", function () {
        var requestID = $(this).data('id');
        document.getElementById('txtBusinessRejectRequestId').value = requestID;
    });
```

The modal window looks like this:

```
   <div id="BusinessRejectModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter reason for rejection</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    Request ID: <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessRejectRequestId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" BorderStyle="None" Text="test line"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br /><br />
                    Reason for Rejection: 
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessRejectReason" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitBusinessRejectModal" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="btnSubmitBusinessRejectModal_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal window essentially allows the user to input a description of the request which is then read, along with the requestid, using c# once the button is clicked.

Hope this helps anyone else having the same issue. Cheers